# iOS: HTTPS GET: Empty Response from server after the app returns back from the lock screen

Tags: ios, https, youtube, response, moya

**Problem:**
**HTTPS** GET returns empty response if sent within 1-2 seconds after returning to the app from the lock-screen.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Start my app. It shows a newsfeed in a TableView on the screen.
2. Lock the iPhone.
3. Unlock the iPhone
4. **Within 1-2 seconds** do the pull-to-refresh on TableView so it sends HTTPS GET request to YouTube to fetch the list of videos from the particular channel.

**Expected Result:** I get the response from YouTube with the list of videos.

**Actual Result:** I get "empty response" log from Moya.

**Note:** the next same pull to refresh works. If you wait for 2 secs and do the pull to refresh - also works perfectly. STRANGE!

**Context:**
iOS
Swift
Moya

Who knows why? Any clue? Broke my brains.

**UPD**
The link to the code: https://yadi.sk/d/Feu0FZkdu9ogr
Please try and experience it.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the issue is the GET request and the resulting response, and not, for example, some UI related issue? We really need [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Rob will attach. I am sure that this is not UI issue. I log all network activity and read it :)

Comment: @Rob attached the actual code. Please try.